# many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problems with my many to many relationships.

I have setup the appropriate connections, linking the join tables.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => "users_logins", :foreign_key => "login_id" 
has_and_belongs_to_many ....
```

when I try to search using User.find(:all, :include => :login ...)

I get the result that I want, but when i try to do User.login.name it returns nomethod found

I have the basic User information, but I want to get all the login information, whether it be 10 entries, but I cannot get the information to be viewable!! :(

Comment: thanks Kandad :) btw, I rendered the result set, and I get all the information, ... @login @attributes { name = "test" } ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User.login would be an array and hence the "nomethod" error . Try `user.logins[0].name` or `user.login[0].name` .

Comment: cheers, that was a stupid question on my part...no sleep makes you do stupid things :)